# 3 buttons with same CSS and JS are not working, 1st button is working fine but rest 2 buttons are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, modal-dialog

https://jsfiddle.net/SaifMinhaz/m1heq9z8/

Please have a look at this faddle, 3 buttons with exact same class, CSS, and JavaScript with a different id. Only 1st button is working completely fine but the 2nd and 3rd buttons are not working. Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance. I'm attaching the code below.
Extra: It would be very helpful for me if you can suggest me, how I can put multiple photos stacked in the modal body without losing the shape of the modal. It will show a single photo in the modal body but if someone swap over the picture then the next picture will arrive. Thank you so much.

```js
// Modal
// Get DOM Elements
const modal = document.querySelector('#my-modal');
const modalBtn = document.querySelector('#modal-btn');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close');

// Events
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

// Open
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Close
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Close If Outside Click
function outsideClick(e) {
  if (e.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
/* Modal section styling */

:root {
    --modal-duration: 1s;
    --modal-color: crimson;
  }
  
  .button {
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    background: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .button:hover {
    color: crimson;
    background: none;
  }
  
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  
  .modal-content {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 60%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    animation-name: modalopen;
    animation-duration: var(--modal-duration);
  }
  
  .modal-header h2,
  .modal-footer h3 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .modal-header {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .modal-body {
    padding: 10px 5px 1px 5px;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  .modal-footer {
    background: var(--modal-color);
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .close {
    color: #ccc;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  @keyframes modalopen {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!-- Modal Button 1 start -->
<button id="modal-btn" class="button">Parkit</button>
<div id="my-modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Vehicle Parking Application</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="https://thefinancialexpress.com.bd/uploads/1575560371.jpg" alt="Vehicle Parking Application" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <p>
      Footer
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 1 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 2 start -->
<button id="modal-btn2" class="button">IPDC IMS</button>
<div id="my-modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Asset Management System</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="#" alt="Asset Management System" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 2 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 3 start -->
<button id="modal-btn3" class="button">Gaming Website</button>
<div id="my-modal3" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Gaming Website</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 3 end -->
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` only finds the first element that matches the query. When you have more than one element to query for, you need to use `querySelectorAll` and iterate for each item that matches the query.

UPDATED: per comment, the code blocks are modified to toggle respective modal DIVs to each button.

See the modified example below.

```js
// Modal
// Get DOM Elements
const modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
const modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.close');

// Events
modalBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', openModal));
closeBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', closeModal));
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

// Open
function openModal(e) {
  const id = e.target.dataset.id;
  const target = document.querySelector(`.modal[data-id="${id}"]`);
  target.style.display = 'block';
}

// Close
function closeModal() {
  modal.forEach(el => el.style.display = 'none');
}

// Close If Outside Click
function outsideClick(e) {
  // NOTE: add a conditional to check clicking outside modal area
  // closeModal();
}
```

```css
/* Modal section styling */

 :root {
  --modal-duration: 1s;
  --modal-color: crimson;
}

.button {
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  background: crimson;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  color: crimson;
  background: none;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 60%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  animation-name: modalopen;
  animation-duration: var(--modal-duration);
}

.modal-header h2,
.modal-footer h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-header {
  background: var(--modal-color);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 10px 5px 1px 5px;
  background: #fff;
}

.modal-footer {
  background: var(--modal-color);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.close {
  color: #ccc;
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@keyframes modalopen {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Modal Button 1 start -->
<button id="modal-btn" data-id="modal1" class="button">Parkit</button>
<div id="my-modal" data-id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Vehicle Parking Application</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="https://thefinancialexpress.com.bd/uploads/1575560371.jpg" alt="Vehicle Parking Application" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <p>
        Footer
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 1 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 2 start -->
<button id="modal-btn2" data-id="modal2" class="button">IPDC IMS</button>
<div id="my-modal2" data-id="modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Asset Management System</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="#" alt="Asset Management System" class="responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 2 end -->

<!-- Modal Button 3 start -->
<button id="modal-btn3" data-id="modal3" class="button">Gaming Website</button>
<div id="my-modal3" data-id="modal3" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h3>Gaming Website</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Button 3 end -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment but in this solution, all the buttons are showing the exact output of the first button!

Comment: @MinhazulIslamSaif Just edited the code to show respective modal content to each button. You’d need to add a new logic to check for clicking outside though.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bumhan Yu. It really helped me to solve my problem